# Chance of data mismatch when Multiple users share datafiles

Tags: jmeter

The sceanrio is: change user password(User will change password to new password).

I have to run a fixed number of users for 1hr duration.

Input I have is: A fixed number of userids set to the same password.

The data file (username,password,newpassword) in case of 3 users ( users can vary Up to 200) is like:

```
u1,p1,newp1
u2,p1,newp1
u3,p1,newp1
u1,newp1,newp2
u2,newp1,newp2
u3,newp1,newp2
u1,newp2,newp3
u2,newp2,newp3
u3,newp2,newp3....
```

The mode used for csv data config  is shared across " all threads".

So basically all users will start with password p1 and change it to newp1 in the first iteration. Then for next iteration the current password will be newp1 and it will changed to newp1.

Initially I will use a 5-10 minute ramp up.

The doubt is: This is working in case of few users. But is it sure that all the users will pick the data from csv in the correct order for a prolonged duration?

For example  if some of the users finish the iteration earlier will they pick the userids already in process by other ids?

Any miss match will affect the execution since assumption is the users will pick the correct current and new passwords. Also one failure will fail all reamaining iterations.

Please check this approach is correct and suggest modifications if needed. Also feel free to suggest if you have a better approach for the scenario.

Comment: As per my understanding, this approach is correct as csv data set config will take care of all this thing

Comment: It will work fine for as many users as you want. Tested it many times. Works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks to  both of you..I was so confused to proceed with large no of  users thats why asked.